Very confused about functions...
I need to give an expression for lines of symmetry in a graph of y =  1/sin⁡(4x+π/3). So to solve this I am looking for lines of symmetry in y = sin(4x + π/3) by transforming the points of symmetry of a sin(x) graph - which are π/2 + nπ , n∈Z.
What I don't understand is the maths behind this transformation (I have seen the answer). It's done by equating the arguments and solving, but I am very confused about how and why this works. As I read more about it I became more confused, although I did get to understand that I have a very weak grasp on the concept of a function.
And this is where my confusion culminated. if I wanted to transform sin(x) into sin(4x + π/3) I would need to move left by π/3 and squash by a scale factor of 4. Why would I not squash first and then shift, because the π/3 is not actually "touching" the 4 inside the sine function (if that makes sense). I would see this approach working if I factored out the 4, and shifted left by π/12, then squashed by 4, that way both things are "touching" the 4. But this is wrong and I am not sure why.
Can anyone explain why I can equate the arguments, and then also why the π/3 is done before the squash even though it doesn't "touch" the 4. I am aware that my first question is easier to answer, because the second one is more of a situational panic that seems harder to decipher.
This is a very novice question, but going to university next year will be the first time I have access to a maths teacher, so currently I have nowhere else to ask.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

What do you mean by "equating the arguments"?

Notice that it is the graph of $y=\sin(4x)$ that is shifted left by $\frac{\pi}{12}$. To get the line of symmetry of $y=\sin(4x)$ you have to consider the period.

To convince yourself that the horizontal shift is done before the horizontal compression, you can think about how a particular point, say an intercept, gets transformed. For example, $\sin(x)$ equals zero when $x=0$. So $\sin(x+\pi/3)$ will equal zero when $x+\pi/3=0$, or when $x=-\pi/3$. And $\sin(4x+\pi/3)$ will equal zero when $4x=-\pi/3$, or when $x= -\pi/12$. This means that the graph of $\sin(x+\pi/3)$ is shifted left by $\pi/3$ relative to the graph of $\sin(x)$. (The horizontal intercept at the origin moved $\pi/3$ units to the left.) And the graph of $\sin(4x+\pi/3)$ is compressed horizontally relative to the graph of $\sin(x+\pi/3)$ by a factor of $4$. (The horizontal intercept at $-\pi/3$ got squashed in toward the origin.)
A second way to say this: you know that the graph of $f(4x)$ is obtained from the graph of $f(x)$ by compressing horizontally by a factor of $4$. In this example, the graph that is getting squashed is that of $f(x)=\sin(x+\pi/3)$. This is the $\sin(x)$ graph shifted $\pi/3$ units to the left. So the shift has already been done before you start squashing.
Slightly more formally, let's think about how the function that maps $x$ to $\sin(4x+\pi/3)$ is built out of three simpler functions,
\begin{align}
s(x) &= \sin(x),\\
t(x) &= x+\pi/3,\\
d(x) &= 4x.
\end{align}
To obtain $s(t(x))$ we would replace every occurrence of $x$ in the expression for $s(x)$ with $t(x)$, that is, with $x+\pi/3$. So we get
$$
s(t(x)) = \sin(x+\pi/3).
$$
Similarly, to obtain $s(t(d(x)))$ we would replace every occurrence of $x$ in the expression for $s(t(x))$ with $d(x)$, that is, with $4x$. So we get
$$
s(t(d(x)) = \sin(4x+\pi/3).
$$
To think about how the graph of $s(t(d(x)))$ compares with the graph of $s(x)$, we have to work from the outside in: the function $s$ gives us a wavy line; the function $t$ shifts that wavy line horizontally; and the function $d$ compresses the shifted wavy line horizontally.
